# How to use gnu sed to replace all but one word?

Tags: regex, sed, gnu

I have this text (the_file.txt):

```
one two three four
five six seven eight
nine ten eleven twelve
thirteen fourteen fifteen sixteen
```

I want to replace each word by a "Z", except the word "six", using gnu sed. I  did it this way:

```
sed 's/\<\([^s]\|.[^i]\|.[^ ][^x]\|[^ ]\{4\}\)[^ ]*/Z/g' the_file.txt
```

And it works:

```
Z Z Z Z
Z six Z Z
Z Z Z Z
Z Z Z Z
```

My question is: is there an easier way to do it? Because if there were two or three words I'd like to preserve, the regex becomes really ugly.

I know it would be easier to do it with other tools (awk for example), but I'm interested in improving my sed abilities, maybe using a little bit of scripting.

Thanks.

Comment: just fyi: PCRE like regex have simpler constructs to achieve this `perl -pe 's/\b(six|one|eleven)\b(*SKIP)(*F)|[a-z]+/Z/g' ip.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For multiple words:

```
$ sed -E 's/\<(six|one|eleven)\>/\n&/g; s/(^| )\S+/\1Z/g; s/\n//g' file
one Z Z Z
Z six Z Z
Z Z eleven Z
Z Z Z Z
```

The above puts a newline before every target word then replaces every sequence of non-spaces preceded by a blank char or at the start of the input string (i.e. not our target words as those are now preceded by a newline) with a Z then removes the newlines added in the first step.

Answer (score 0):

The following is probably easier to maintain:

```
sed 's/\(six\)\|\([^ ]\+\)/\1Z/g;s/sixZ/six/g'
```

It first replaces everyting to `Z` with the exception of `six` which gets replaced with `sixZ`, which is then fixed by the second substitution.